# Touch-pads gesture disabled after connect a bluetooth mouse

Tags: mouse, 18.04, touchpad, bluetooth, multi-touch

My **touch-pad's gesture has been disable** just after I had connected my mouse in Bluetooth.

I deleted my mouse device profile in the Bluetooth manager and disabled Bluetooth. I restarted my system.

**I can't:**

- 4 fingers drag down/up (for switch desktop)

**I can:**

- move cursor
- 1 finger right click
- 2 fingers left click

Have you any idea to solve this problem?

A conflict ? A disabled option ?

**Specs :**

- Xiaomi notebook pro
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Microsoft Arc Mouse last generation (for the last time !)